# How to prevent URL access to paperclip uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

My app uses File.read() to read the attachments uploaded using paperclip so I need to lock URL access to these uploaded files. Currently the uploads are saved in public/system folder. How can I prevent URL access to these uploaded files?

My model definition looks as follows:

```
class Audio < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :file,
  {
        url: "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:hash.:extension",
        hash_secret: 'd6721ee3e213c55a56577ed527f6312a7000302e3f6ada66a522c80f92f10ffc1e283959503ed3fa54fa6599689760190f16625b998b583e9de15da356839339'
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]

end
```

Thanks!